# Cannot declare class Model, because the name is already in use; PHP

Tags: php

Estoy teniendo este error, pero no es el caso de que el nombre ya este usado. Es mas estaba funcionando y sigue funcionando correctamente en otras partes del código.

La clase `Model` es una clase abstracta que conecta a la base de datos, las clases que necesitan conectar a la bd extienden la clase`Model`.

El error ocurre cuando en un mismo archivo llamo a dos metodos de distintas clases, estas dos clases extienden la clase `Model`.

```
//clase usuario
require_once($CLASES_DIR . 'usuario.class.php');
$usu = New usuario();

$usu->setCorreo($correo);
//metodo de la clase usuario
$id_cl = $usu->id();

//Llamo clase suscripcion
require_once($CLASES_DIR . 'suscripcion.class.php');
$sus = New suscripcion();
```

Lo único distinto al resto del código donde funciona es que en en un mismo archivo llamo a dos clases. 
Como puedo solucionar esto?

EDIT: agrego los archivos suscripcion.class.php y usuario.class.php

```
<?php
require('model.php');
class suscripcion extends Model{

private $id;
private $id_usu;
private $t_credito;
private $tipo_sus;
private $fecha_i;
private $fecha_f;

function __construct($id='',$id_usu='',$t_credito='',$tipo_sus='',$fecha_i='',$fecha_f=''){
    //Cargo el constructor de la superclase
    parent::__construct();

    $this->id = $id;
    $this->id_usu = $id_usu;
    $this->t_credito = $t_credito;
    $this->tipo_sus = $tipo_sus;
    $this->fecha_i = $fecha_i;
    $this->fecha_f = $fecha_f;
}
```

---

```
?php
require('model.php');
class usuario extends Model{
private $id;
private $nombre;
private $apellido;
private $correo;
private $contraseña;
private $tel;
private $suscripto; //boolean
private $t_credito;
private $estado;  

function __construct($id='',$nombre='',$apellido='',$correo='',$contraseña='',
$tel='',$suscripto='',$t_credito='',$estado=''){

//Cargo el constructor de la superclase
parent::__construct();

$this->id=$id;
$this->nombre=$nombre;
$this->apellido=$apellido;
$this->correo=$correo;
$this->contraseña=$contraseña;
$this->tel=$tel;
$this->suscripto=$suscripto;
$this->t_credito=$t_credito;
$this->estado=$estado;
```

}

---

```
?php

    abstract class Model{

        protected $_db;


        public function __construct(){
            // Se conecta a la DB al instanciar la clase
            $this->_db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
            if ( $this->_db->connect_errno ){
                echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: ". $this->_db->connect_error;
                return;
            }

            $this->_db->set_charset(DB_CHARSET);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Seria bueno que pusieras los archivos que están involucrados, cuales de ellos extienden a Model?

Comment: @Sergio1871 ahi coloque los archivos

Comment: en que archivo te marca el error y en que linea?

Comment: en la clase model, la cual conecta a la base de datos, linea 3 @Sergio1871

Comment: Puede que sea el hecho de que estas llamando el require dos veces, una en la clase usuario y otra en la clase suscripción, intententa quitando el requiere('model.php') de la última clase que pusiste en tu main, en este casi de suscripciones

Comment: Ahora anduvo, quite el requiere  model de la clase suscripcion como tu dijiste! Muchas gracias, asumía como que eso estaba bien y nunca iba a probar quitarlo.@Sergio1871

Answer (score 3):

el compañero de arriba tiene razón, al invocar dos clases:

```
//clase usuario
require_once($CLASES_DIR . 'usuario.class.php');
$usu = New usuario();
```

Y:

```
//Llamo clase suscripcion
require_once($CLASES_DIR . 'suscripcion.class.php');
$sus = New suscripcion();
```

estás invocando dos veces el 'model.php', por que en ambas clases las incluyes:

```
 require('model.php');
```

recuerda que tanto **require** como **include** insertan código las n cantidad de veces que los invoques o uses sin importar si ya haz llamado el archivo con aterioridad, por ello al hacer un doble

```
 require('model.php');
```

te sale la advertencia:

```
 Cannot declare class 'Model', because the name is already in use;
 //Traducción al Español:
 No se puede declarar la clase 'model' , porque el nombre ya está en uso;
```

Haciendo referencia a que ya haz usado el:

```
  require('model.php');
```

Recuerda que en php se vuelve todo un solo archivo al procesar y esta advertencia te dice que estas escribiendo el mismo código dos veces
la solución es fácil, al trabajar con PDO, Clases y Objetos recuerda utilizar:

```
include_once o require_once
```

ya que estos (Citando la documentacion de PHP):

> La sentencia require_once es idéntica a require excepto que PHP verificará si el archivo ya ha sido incluido y si es así, no se incluye (require) de nuevo.
>
> La sentencia include_once incluye y evalúa el fichero especificado durante la ejecución del script. Tiene un comportamiento similar al de la sentencia include, siendo la única diferencia de que si el código del fichero ya ha sido incluido, no se volverá a incluir, e include_once devolverá TRUE. Como su nombre indica, el fichero será incluido solamente una vez.

Te invito a que leas la documentación, se que es difícil por el tiempo, pero créeme, leer la documentación te evitará ahogarte en un vaso de agua (además sabras la diferencia entre Include y Require :P )!

Answer (score 0):

ME ha sucedido por ejemplo al usar wordpress y tener que usar requiere en múltiples archivos para llamar a una clase que extiende de otra.
El problema con usar un require o include es que PHP lo interpreta como si todo el código estuviera junto entonces si haces un require de una clase intermedia que en el archivo hace require a MODEL entonces es como si la declaradas 2 veces.